# Create User API Mysql auto-increment bug

Tags: javascript, mysql, api

I am trying to get a simple create user function running, but keep getting a strange sql error which I am assuming comes from some sort of error around my use of the auto-increment key for mysql, but have been unable to identify the actual issue.

Below is an example of my server code:

```
app.post('/createPhysician', function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.body);
    // do input checking here
    var createPromise = interact.createPhysician(req.body.physicianID,
    req.body.firstName,
    req.body.lastName,
    req.body.yearNum,
    req.body.position,
    req.body.isAttending,
    req.body.highRiskTrained)

    //did promise
    createPromise.then(function(createResponse) {
        res.status(200).json({"status":"success"}); // .end because we just want to return an empty response
    }).catch(function(err) {
        console.log(err);
        res.status(500).json(err);
    });
});
```

Below is the interact.sql code for the func:

```
createPhysician: function(
firstName,
lastName,
yearNum,
position,
isAttending,
highRiskTrained) {
    var qry = "insert into Physician (firstName, lastName, yearNum, position, isAttending, highRiskTrained) values \
    ('"+firstName+"', '"+lastName+"', "+yearNum+", '"+position+"', "+isAttending+", "+highRiskTrained+");";
    return runQuery(qry);
}
```

Below is description of my mysql table:
[image]

Below is what I am entering for a body into Postman:

```
{
    "firstName": "firstName",
    "lastName": "lastName",
    "yearNum": 1,
    "position": "coder",
    "isAttending": 1,
    "highRiskTrained": 0
}
```

Below is the error that I get in Postman from the request:

```
{
    "code": "ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR",
    "errno": 1054,
    "sqlMessage": "Unknown column 'coder' in 'field list'",
    "sqlState": "42S22",
    "index": 0,
    "sql": "insert into Physician (firstName, lastName, yearNum, position, isAttending, highRiskTrained) values         ('undefined', 'firstName', lastName, '1', coder, 1);"
}
```

The output of the API console log for the request body is below:

```
{ firstName: 'firstName',
  lastName: 'lastName',
  yearNum: 1,
  position: 'coder',
  isAttending: 1,
  highRiskTrained: 0 }
```

Comment: The error tells that there is no column `coder` in your table. Just like you can also see in the image of the table you have posted. But to be honest i also still don't get why this error is throwed here due to you pass `coder` as a value and not as a column....

Comment: `app.post('/createPhysician', function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.body);` can you post this console output?

Comment: Should you even be passing `physicianId` into the `createPhysician` function? It looks like it has no such parameter defined and that doing so would "shift" the values you are passing in, which is why "lastName" and "coder" end up without delimiters; and the value for highRiskTrained is not even included in the query.

Comment: @messerbill That is why I am getting confused too, it's like the sql is just shifting the single quotes down one parameter... Also I have posted the output for that `console.log()` which appears to print the expected value...

Comment: @Drew does Uueerdo's comment make the solution?

Comment: @Uueerdo I had overlooked this for days!!! Deleting that fixed it!

Comment: @Uueerdo so if it is fixed now please answer the question to receive your reputation ;) otherwise please answer the question by yourself Drew ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When wrapping a query with a function, make sure the proper parameters are used by the query AND passed into the function into the correctly.

*It always feels a little weird putting a formal answer to what ends up being little more than a typo, but I suppose you never know who might need the same kind of typo pointed out.*